# Firebase best option for storing images

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

I'm building a personal photography portfolio using firebase and I am not sure on which way of hosting the images is the most efficient / cost effective.

Currently I have the website hosted on firebase with the images being accessed from a storage bucket every time the page is loaded. Preferential for myself as it makes managment easier and the page generates on the fly as more images are added to the bucket.

Most sites refer to the firebase storage for images, but mine can be 5MB+ and there are over 40 of them. I have thought of adding a CDN but I'm not sure I will have the traffic for that.

However, I have considered just adding the images to the assets of the Angular page and putting them all in hosting, so that no firebase storage calls are made.

Is there a best practice method for this?

Answer (score 1):

I've currently working on a website that deals with creating custom images and saving images to go within these new ones. I use Cloudinary. I've not had to pay for it yet and it has a powerful API option to be able to edit the image too.

With this you can upload them and just call the link to load then I'm and their is also a angular package too

Comment: Not sure this currently is working with Angular 13(?) unless I am working with the wrong version.

Comment: I use the HTTP API